# How do I fake mozilla access using urllib?

Tags: python, api, urllib

I'm new to python and programming in general, so to learn I wrote a bot that finds the subscribers of a channel every second or so. It was working fine until later today I think the api thinks I'm a bot, and I know that you can fake it using the header thing, but I can't figure out how to do it. Here's the code:

```
key = ""
test_subs = 1000


while True:
    channel_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=UCHLv3UOtSC9EcR2Ybqmci8g&key=" + key

    channel_data = urllib.request.urlopen(channel_url).read()

    channel_subs = json.loads(channel_data)["items"][0]["statistics"]["subscriberCount"]
```

Comment: Why wouldn't the API think your a bot? Its an a interface for bots to connect to. If it blocked you I don't think that would be why.

Comment: @RedKnite maybe because too many requests in a matter of seconds? I don't really use APIs so correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @TheTechRobo36414519 Yep found the limits page and that was basicly it.

Comment: @RedKnite Glad I could help.

Comment: @DevynMeneses In what way did is stop working? Did it give an error message or what?

Comment: @RedKnite it's giving the HTTP 403 forbidden error message. It's not due to the quota.

Comment: @RedKnite Why was your answer deleted?

Comment: @TheTechRobo36414519 OP said that they made at most 10,000 requests in a day when I thought the problem was that they were making 86,400. That means that my answer was just false :(

Comment: @DevynMeneses A Forbidden message? Do you need to login to the API with a token or user account?

Comment: @DevynMeneses Trying to go in my browser gives me this: `{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
`. meaning you need to sign up? (the link I used was https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=UCHLv3UOtSC9EcR2Ybqmci8g)

Comment: I also found this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MiEpJRoITsI

Comment: For some reason it started working again, thank you for all the help though! I'll slow down on the requests since @RedKnite pointed that out.